# Android data need to insert in database dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic

We are getting the request from Android app as json array. For example:

```
$var = [{"username":"kp","mailid":"kp@gmail.com","phoneno":"9876543563","groupname":"android"}]';
```

I want to make this static data (kp, kp@gmail.com, 9876543563, android) as dynamic to insert the values into database.

In what method we are getting the data? And from an android app, is it POST or GET variable, or an other method? Please let me know how to make this value dynamic which is coming from the android app.

Comment: please describe step by step what do you need. for now it's impossible to understand

Comment: The values kp, kp@gmail.com, 9876543563, android are the form submitted values from a mobile app. In a PHP page I want to insert this data into database.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

How to do you want to send the data from Android App? Is it needed to be namely JSON-format?
I think the most useful case is to use usual, e.g., POST data and retrieve this using base methods to save it inside PHP. You can use, of course, GET format for 'short' request.

For instance,

Android sends using GET: `http://yourcompany.com/senddata?username=name&mailid=e@yourmail.com`

You PHP code (very-very-very simple approach):

```
    /// ... initialization...

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES ('". ($_POST["username"]) . "', '". ($_POST["mailid"]) . "')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
```

[PHP insert example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

To create POST or GET request in Android I would recommend to use JSOUP library
[Download](https://jsoup.org/download)
 A simple example for jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://yourcompany.com/url?var1=a").get();
```